# Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Saml2' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, saml, saml-2.0

I'm on Laravel 5, I'm trying to integrate SAML 2.0 with it. I've found this package = https://github.com/aacotroneo/laravel-saml2

I tried follow their steps, but at the end when I use

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class SAMLController extends Controller {


    public function adminSignIn(){
        return Saml2::login(URL::full());
    }
}
```

I've already added

**provider**

```
'Aacotroneo\Saml2\Saml2ServiceProvider',
```

**aliases**

```
'Saml2'               => 'Aacotroneo\Saml2\Facades\Saml2Auth',
```

---

Why do I still get this error?

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Saml2' not found

**Note :** I've even retry after `sudo composer dumpauto`, same result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use full namespace for the facade:

```
\Saml2::login(URL::full());
```

Or add this to the top of the class:

```
use Saml2;
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to explicitly write "use" on top

> use Saml2;

This might work.